# Absolute positioned div expands the relative positioned parent div

Tags: css

I have searched various questions, which all seem to be able to extend absolute children beyond their relative parent. I am trying to avoid this.

I have a div with position: relative; that contains a div with position: absolute; that i want to always sit at the bottom of the div. When I set bottom:0px; the absolute child extends beyond the parent div with 4 px. It can be solved by setting bottom:4px; but when I begin making the site responsive such absolute numbers won't do the trick.

html:

```
<a href="her.html">
    <div class="next_movie">
        <img src="img/her_header.jpg" alt="Picture from the movie 'Her'">
        <div class="movie_info">
           <h2>Her (2013) March 6th in AUD1</h2>
         </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

css:

```
.movies {
    width: 616.6px;
    height:663px;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    margin-top: 75px;
    position: absolute;
    left:233.3px;;
}
.movie_info, .poster_info {
    color:white;
}
.next_movie {
    position:relative;
    margin:16.6px;

}
.movie_info{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:582.5px;
    height:56.6px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:white;
    font-size:25px;
    line-height: 2.3;
}
.movie_info h2 {
    margin-left:15.8px;
}
```

Test version of the site sits here:
http://jhalland.dk/test/

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing height from your movie_info styles. Or you can change it to min-height. You have conflicting rules since you've defined line-height as 2.3